# AWS will soon be sponsoring Quantum Computing

Tags: discussion

We're thrilled to announce that [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/) will be sponsoring Quantum Computing starting on **January 16, 2023 through January 16, 2024**. We wanted to give you a heads-up and walk you through what that means.

### How and where will the sponsorship be displayed?

The sponsorship will be found on the right side of the header at the top of the site similar to what you see below.

[image: Quantum Computing Stack Exchange Home Page with AWS Logo]

### What else changes?

Not a thing! Borrowing from [the original MSE announcement on sponsorships](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307861/site-sponsorships-bringing-resources-back-to-stack-exchange):

> First — sponsors do not own these Q&A sites. Sponsors work alongside our communities who ultimately build these sites. Communities ask the questions; communities create the tags; communities conduct elections as they do now, and we are not renaming our current sites like a garish sport stadium to the highest bidder. Any ads a sponsor submits still have go through our crazy-strict ad editorial process… as it has always been. Companies do not have access to personal data, and all Q&A content remains irrevocably licensed under Creative Commons for sharing and attribution.

Sponsorships are a tool that our clients can use to let folks who could be interested in their products know about them in a non-intrusive way.

### What if I've found a design glitch/bug?

If something looks off, please report it as a [bug](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug) so we can investigate and squash it.

That's all. If you have any other questions or concerns, please leave them as answers below.

Lastly, thank you. These types of partnerships help us bring more resources to our communities, and they wouldn't be possible without the work you've put into making Quantum Computing successful.

Comment: I don't see this logo on Firefox browser (Windows OS). I do see it on Android Chrome.